# Who throws the segmentation fault?

Tags: c, unix, data-structures, operating-system

Given the below program.

```
 int main() {
 char *str = "hello word";
 str[0] = 'a';
 return 0;
 }
```

The above program throws segmentation fault. I know it throws because the read only segment contains the hello world, and it cannot be modified. If store instruction that changes from "h" to "a" is done in the L1 cache(inside the processor) and MMU comes into picture only when the page is flushed from L3 to main memory, who throws segmentation fault almost immediately.

The below code which is effectively doing the same thing, doesn't cause any segmentation fault. Why?

```
 int main() {
 char str[] = {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','\0'};
 str[0] = 'a';
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The processor cache has tags associated with each cache line that tell it the permissions applied to the memory currently held in that cache line. As such, an attempt at writing to read-only memory will (normally) be caught immediately upon attempting to write to the cache; it will not wait until that cache line is flushed to main memory.

As far as the difference between the two examples goes, it's pretty simple: the first defines a statically allocated string literal. Attempting to modify that string literal causes undefined behavior. The second defines an array of char that is initialized to a particular value -- but after it's initialized, it's pretty much like any other array. In particular, the result of modifying the content of the array is well defined.

Comment: So, you mean cache controller is throwing the exception?

Comment: @Bala: Part of the CPU does anyway -- I don't believe either AMD or Intel specifies whether that particular exception comes from the cache controller or the "memory write" functional unit. It's the sort of thing that could even vary from one CPU to another.

Comment: -1, the first string is allocated in read only segment and the second allocated on the stack. In both cases it is array of chars.

Comment: @max taldykin: Sorry, but you're simply wrong. The first isn't necessarily allocated in read-only memory (e.g., on most compilers under MS-DOS, it wouldn't have been). The second isn't necessarily allocated on the stack (e.g., on a compiler running on an IBM mainframe it wouldn't be). Part of the reason that the first is undefined is that separate string literals are allowed to share storage. For example, if I have `char *s="This is a string"` and `char *y="string"`, the compiler can merge the two, and have y point into the middle of the storage allocated for x -- but it's not necessarily R/O.

Comment: yes, you are right, it's implementation dependent. But in this case segfault is generated because program tries to write to readonly data segment. On some other system, or with other linking options it could run without error.

Answer (score 2):

In the second, you are making a copy. While in the first you aren't.

```
char str[] = {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','\0'};
```

Here `str` is an array created on stack. To `str`, contents are being copied. How ever in -

```
char *str = "hello word";
```

`str` is pointing to data residing in non-modifiable section. So, you can't and when tried results segmentation fault.

---

**Description for comments**

I don't think, for the primitive data types C and C++ varies it's rules. From ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E), **Section 8.5.2**

```
1. A char array (whether plain char, signed char, or unsigned char) can be 
   initialized by a string- literal (optionally enclosed in braces); a wchar_t 
   array can be initialized by a wide string-literal (option- ally enclosed in 
   braces); successive characters of the string-literal initialize the members of 
   the array.

     [Example:
           char msg[] = "Syntax error on line %s\n"; shows a character array 
           whose members are initialized with a string-literal. Note that because 
           ’\n’ is a single character and because a trailing ’\0’ is appended, 
           sizeof(msg) is 25. 
     ] 

2. There shall not be more initializers than there are array elements. 

    [Example:
          char cv[4] = "asdf" ;// error is ill-formed since there is no space for the implied trailing ’\0’. 
    ]
```

So, example 2 clears the doubt.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Also, a NULL terminating character is not required. It's added by default in the second case.

Comment: Is this actually specified in the C standards?

Comment: @Kinopiko - I amn't sure of where it is specified in the C Standard. Lets check out with an example, if it added by default or not. http://ideone.com/Yymfv

Comment: @Kinopiko @Bala - Added the citations from the standard.

Comment: There's no "copy" here ... there's simply a read/write array initialized with the same characters as in the string literal. And this "answer" doesn't address the question about cache levels.

Comment: @Jim Balter - Had if my answer been fully answered to the question, probably OP might have marked my answer as accepted ;)

Comment: @Mahesh If pigs had wings they could fly.